How to include a simple ansible vault file and refer its content from the whole ansible workspace?
I am thinking on a trival secret ansible vault:
I have a secret.yml in my inventory, which is the single encrypted file in my ansible workspace, containing all the secret data. Its structure is very simple:
somewhere_a_password: fds3t435re
other_key: 4352kjh3kj435
thing_i_wont_say: 3245lkh243k5jh

I want to refer the keys in this yml in my whole workspace (which is organized anyways as usual).
I am calling ansible with this:
ansible-playbook -i ./inv/ --ask-vault-pass -e @./inv/secret.yml -vvvv playbooks/$1.yml

So, my secret.yml must be included! And yes, of course it is asking for my vault pass.
I refer the secret keys in my tasks, for example, on this way:
- name: Create postgresql user
  community.postgresql.postgresql_user:
    name: a_user
    password: "{{ somewhere_a_password }}"
    state: present
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres

However, I get this error:
[WARNING]: Skipping 'somewhere_a_password' as this is not a valid group definition

Why? What is going on? Unfortunately, ansible-vault does not deserve a medal for its documentation quality.

Sometimes docs have the habit that they are talking about everything, except what is needed. It might be also an ansible bug, I do not know - in some hours, I could finally find some example similar extra vars, and these seemed working well.
After source debugging I found that this extra_vars file format has to follow a syntax organized after the hosts or host groups. To define extra vars visible everywhere, we need this syntax:
---
all:
  vars:
    somewhere_a_password: fds3t435re
    other_key: 4352kjh3kj435
    thing_i_wont_say: 3245lkh243k5jh

In general, how things look in the brain of the ansible, this playbook might help a lot:
- name: Print debugging info
  hosts:
    - <any host you have, does not matter>
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: print debug info
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        #var: ansible_facts
        #var: inventory_hostname
        var: vars
        verbosity: 4


If a better answer happens, that will get the pipe.
